# How to add webscraped data to a set in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, set

I'm trying to webscrape URLs from a website and send them to a .CSV file using a set so that duplicate URLs are removed. I understand what a set is and how to create a set, I just don't understand how to send webscraped data to a set. I'm assuming it's in the for loop but I'm newish to Python and am not quite sure. Here is the tail end of my code:

```
url_list=soup.find_all('a')
with open('HTMLList.csv','w',newline="") as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\r')
    for link in url_list:
        url=str(link.get('href'))
        if url:
            if 'https://www.example.com' not in url:
                url = 'https://www.example.com' + url
            writer.writerow([url])
f.close()
```

I know that I need to create a set() and add the URLs to the set but am unsure how and I'm told that it will also get rid of any duplicates, which would be great. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think all you need to do, if you wrote your text file correctly, is read the entire text file into a variable, then put it in a list, or you could just write things line by line, then for each line in the file add it to a list or set

Comment: you have a test url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a set, add the URLs to the set, then write it to file

```
url_list=set()
for link in url_list:
        url=str(link.get('href'))
        if url:
            if 'https://www.example.com' not in url:
                url = 'https://www.example.com' + url
            url_list.add(url)

with open('HTMLList.csv','w',newline="") as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=' ',lineterminator='\r')
    for i in url_list:
        writer.writerow([i])
```

Comment: No need to initialize the set with an empty list: `set() == set([])`

Comment: @MattM. I forgot I already have url_list=soup.find_all('a') at the beginning of the section. Would the same thing still work? And at the end "for i in x" what is the x? It isn't defined anywhere. Might be a stupid question. Sorry if it is.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. That should be url_list, edited my answer. The idea is that we use the existing code for writing your file with the set we created in the loop.

Comment: When I do that I don't get any data. It processes without an error but the .CSV file is blank. Don't I need the part at the top of my code (url_list=soup.find_all('a'))?

Comment: Yes, this was primarily meant to show how to process first into a set and then into a file. You will need to tweak a few things as needed to use your existing scraping code with the intermediate step of writing into the set object and then into the file rather than directly from web to file